# IList<int> throws Null Reference Exception when adding values

Tags: c#, collections, ilist, icollection

I have a class:

```
public class ClientModelData
{
    public int clientID { get; set; }
    public IList<int> LocationIDs { get; set; }
}
```

When I call it:

```
ClientModelData obj = new ClientModelData();
obj.LocationIDs.Add(1);
```

It throws an exception:

```
`((System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<int>)(client.LocationID))' is null`
```

Comment: Create constructor in Class and re-initiate property with new Keyword;
LocationIDs = new List<T>(); // where T can be any class reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LocationIDs` is not initialized therefore it is giving you the error.

```
public IList<int> LocationIDs { get; set; }
```

You should create an instance in the constructor

```
public ClientModelData()
{
  LocationIDs = new List<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize your list with actual object, for example in the constructor. Add this to your class:

```
public ClientModelData()
{
   LocationIDs = new List<int>();
}
```